# Angular CLI 6, Universal: What is the proper way to get cookies from ExpressJS request object?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6, angular-universal, angular-cli-v6

I have this code working on `Angular 5.2.10` and `Angular CLI 1.7.4`:

```
@Injectable()
export class FmCookieService {
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(REQUEST) private _request: Request) { }

  ...
}
```

I'm injecting the `REQUEST` token provided by `@nguniversal/express-engine` and using its value only when on server platform.

I'm trying to upgrade to `Angular 6` and `Angular CLI 6` and I'm getting the following errors when compiling:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\cookie-signature'
ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\etag'
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\destroy'
ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\etag'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\send'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/node_modules/mime/mime.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\send\node_modules\mime'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/content-disposition/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\content-disposition'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\mime-types'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\send'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/node_modules/mime/mime.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\send\node_modules\mime'
ERROR in ./node_modules/serve-static/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\serve-static'
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\destroy'
ERROR in ./node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/streams.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/extend-node.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\send'
ERROR in ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Projects\POCs\cli6-test\node_modules\body-parser\lib'
```

This is supposed to happen in this new version, here are the reasons why [#9827 (comment)](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827#issuecomment-369578814) and here it's the change [@angular/devkit commit diff](https://github.com/angular/devkit/commit/8e7658aabc71829153e0dfccf60cc526142a16dd#diff-085e357d25d94ae495a662c157178fb0L103).

I've found a couple of workarounds I didn't like too much and I ended up doing something like (on `server.ts`):

```
app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      { provide: COOKIES_TOKEN, useValue: options.req.cookies }
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
});
```

And then, I'm using that `COOKIES_TOKEN` when on server platform, but I'm not sure what should be the recommended approach to do this.

Can someone point me what would be the recommended way of accessing the cookies from the ExpressJS request when on server platform?

Comment: Did you solved this issue? I have it also...

Comment: @SandyWeb I solved it by providing the cookies on the `server.ts` and then injecting the appropriate token where needed. Please refer to the last part of my post.